# At what point is $y=5x+965$ to the graph of $y=2x^3-3x^2-247x-7$?

Tags: graphing-functions, tangent-line

Here is the question:

> The line $y=5x+965$ is tangent to the graph of $y=2x^3-3x^2-247x-7$ at the point...?

Anytime I am trying to plot the graph I end up with a line that's basically attached to the $y$-axis.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have a line $y=mx+n$ where $m$ is the gradient. You have a curve $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where $\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=x_0}$ gives you the gradient of the tangent at $x=x_0$. So equate $m$ with  $\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=x_0}$ and solve for $x$ to give you the x-coordinate of the tangential point; y coordinate you can get by replacing in the equation of line.

Answer (score 3):

You have the two lines $$y=5x+965$$ and $$y=2x^3-3x^2-247x-7$$
Since you are trying to find where they intersect, you can substitute the right hand side of the second equation for the $y$ in the first equation. You get $$5x+965=2x^3-3x^2-247x-7$$ which simplifies to $$2x^3-3x^2-252x-972$$
You can factor this into $$(x+6)^2(2x-27)=0$$

The roots are $x=-6$ and $x=13.5$, and substituting them into the first you get $(-6, 935)$ and $(13.5, 1032.5)$ as the points of intersection.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative answer is that you can consider the line y=5x+965 on the form y=kx+m

where k is = 5. 
Then the derivative of $f(x)=2x^3-3x^2-247x-7$ needs to also be 5 in that point.

This means you can set $f'(x)=5 $ and get $6x^2-6x-252=0\Leftrightarrow x_1=-6$ $,x_2=7$

Then you can find f(-6) and f(7). The equation for a tangentline in a point is:

$y-y_1 = k(x-x_1)$ which gives $y=5(x-(-6))+f(-6)$ which is your tangentline.

$y=5(x-7)+f(7)$ is a parallell line to y = 5x+965. with the equation y = 5x -1232

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Substituting the $y$ of the line in the cubic we have:
$$
2x^3-3x^2-252x-972=0
$$
that factorize as $(x+6)^2(2x-27)=0$

So the double root $x=-6 $ gives the point of tangency at $P=(-6,935)$. (Difficult to visualize in a graph)